# Can this be done with docusign template?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out if this is even possible. I create a template with one recipient ( recipe1@outlook.com) with 2 signing tabs. Pretty straightforward. I then allow this template to be shared to a group. I have user A in this group. User A wants to use the template with their document, but their recipient is not the same as what was originally in the template and I don't want the document to go to the original recipient. I want my new recipient to be a substitute for the original recipient. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the template, the recipient is a placeholder. So, in my case, I used the role Customer, with no email or name. Then, when I use the template, I fill in that info. Easy once you know the secret.